# Probability in coin flip

Tags: probability

The question:

Two persons $A$, $B$ simultaneously toss their individual coins, and win $1$ point if head is face up and $0$ points if tails is face up. The probability that the points of $A$ exceeds the points of $B$ after $3$ tosses is...

My attempt:

Because each person have $4$ available options of how many points they will have in the end $(0,1,2,$ and $3)$, the total amount of ways the score could be after $3$ tosses would be $4 \cdot 4 = 16$. The cases in which person $A$ wins would be $(1,0)$, $(2,0)$, $(2,1)$, $(3,0)$, $(3,1)$, and $(3,2)$. So the answer should be $\frac{6}{16}$ or $\frac{3}{8}$.

The actual answer is $\frac{11}{32}$

My question:

Where did I go wrong and how do I do it correctly?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not all of the outcomes (0,0), (0,1), (0,2),... (3,2), (3,3) are equally likely.  Although there are indeed sixteen possible outcomes, unless all outcomes are equiprobable you may **not** simply do the fraction of favorable outcomes compared to total outcomes regardless.  For example, the outcome $(0,1)$ is **three times as likely** to occur as the outcome $(0,0)$.

Approach via a combination of the binomial theorem and the multiplication and addition principles of probability.

If $B$ has zero heads, $A$ wins with at least one head.  The probability of $B$ having zero heads is $\frac{1}{8}$.  The probability of $A$ having at least one head is $\frac{7}{8}$.  The probability of $B$ having zero heads **and** $A$ having at least one head is then $\frac{7}{64}$

If $B$ has one head, $A$ wins with at least two heads.  The probability of $B$ having one head is $\frac{3}{8}$.  The probability of $A$ having at least two heads is $\frac{4}{8}$.  The probability then of both occurring is $\frac{12}{64}$

If $B$ has two heads, $A$ wins only with getting three heads.  The probability of $B$ having two heads is $\frac{3}{8}$.  The probability of $A$ having three heads is $\frac{1}{8}$.  The probability then of both occurring is $\frac{3}{64}$

If $B$ has three heads, $A$ cannot win.

As the sample space can be *partitioned* into the result of how many heads $B$ received as above, the probability that $A$ wins is the sum of the aforementioned probabilities:

$Pr(\text{A wins}) = \frac{7}{64}+\frac{12}{64}+\frac{3}{64}+0 = \frac{22}{64}=\frac{11}{32}$

---

(*didn't see John's answer while typing this extra paragraph, the method is essentially the same*)

An alternate way to view the solution: $1 = Pr(\text{A wins})+Pr(\text{A and B tie}) + Pr(\text{B wins})$

Due to the symmetry of their circumstances, we know that $Pr(\text{A wins})=Pr(\text{B wins})$.  This leaves us with the question of finding $Pr(\text{A and B tie})$

This can occur with either zero heads each, one head each, two heads each, or three heads each.

These occur with probabilities $\frac{1}{64}, \frac{9}{64},\frac{9}{64},\frac{1}{64}$ respectively.

The probability that $A$ and $B$ tie is then $\frac{20}{64}$

This tells us that $Pr(A~\text{wins}) = \frac{1}{2}(1-\frac{20}{64})=\frac{22}{64}=\frac{11}{32}$

Answer (score 4):

Here's another way to look at the problem.

What if they're tied after three coin tosses?

They could get no heads ($1$ possibility), one head each ($9$ possibilities), two heads each ($9$ possibilities), or three heads each ($1$ possibility).

(Why $9$ possibilities for one head each?  $A$ could get a head on the first, second, or third toss, as could $B$.  These are independent, so there are $3\cdot 3=9$ possibilities.  The same reasoning can be applied to two heads each, as well as the total number of possible outcomes $8\cdot 8=64$.)

This adds to $20$ out of $64$ possibilities that they tie, which means $44/64 = 11/16$ probability that they don't.

As $A$ is just as likely to be ahead as $B$, the answer is half this, or $11/32$.

Comment: Just to add. using the identity $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}^2 = \binom{2n}{n}$, we can say generally that the possibilities for a tie after each player flips $n$ coins is $\binom{2n}{n}$. than the chance to win can be easily calculated in the same line and is: $0.5(1 - \dfrac{\binom{2n}{n}}{2^{2n}})$